# Why I can use @list to call an array, but can't use %dict to call a hash in perl?

Tags: perl, sigils

Today I start my perl journey, and now I'm exploring the data type.

My code looks like:

```
@list=(1,2,3,4,5);
%dict=(1,2,3,4,5);

print "$list[0]\n";         # using [ ] to wrap index
print "$dict{1}\n";         # using { } to wrap key

print "@list[2]\n";
print "%dict{2}\n";
```

it seems `$ + var_name` works for both array and hash, but `@ + var_name` can be used to call an array, meanwhile `% + var_name` can't be used to call a hash.

Why?

Comment: With warnings enabled, `%dict=(1,2,3,4,5);` will warn about an odd number of elements.

Comment: And `@list[2]` should throw a warning too.

Comment: **http://stackoverflow.com/a/153725/223226**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@list[2]` works because it is a *slice* of a list.

In Perl 5, a sigil indicates--in a non-technical sense--the *context* of your expression. Except from some of the non-standard behavior that slices have in a scalar context, the basic thought is that the sigil represents what you want to *get out* of the expression.

If you want a scalar out of a hash, it's `$hash{key}`.
If you want a scalar out of an array, it's `$array[0]`. *However*, Perl allows you to get *slices* of the aggregates. And that allows you to retrieve more than one value in a compact expression. Slices take a *list* of indexes. So,

```
@list = @hash{ qw<key1 key2> };
```

gives you a list of items from the hash. And,

```
@list2 = @list[0..3];
```

gives you the first four items from the array. --> For your case, `@list[2]` still has a "list" of indexes, it's just that list is the special case of a "list of one".

As scalar and list contexts were rather well defined, and there was no "hash context", it stayed pretty stable at `$` for scalar and `@` for "lists" and until recently, Perl did not support addressing any variable with `%`. So neither `%hash{@keys}` nor `%hash{key}` had meaning. Now, however, you can dump out pairs of indexes with values by putting the `%` sigil on the front.

```
my %hash = qw<a 1 b 2>;
my @list = %hash{ qw<a b> }; # yields ( 'a', 1, 'b', 2 )
my @l2   = %list[0..2];      # yields ( 0, 'a', 1, '1', 2, 'b' )
```

So, I guess, if you have an older version of Perl, you can't, but if you have 5.20, you can.

---

But for a completist's sake, slices have a non-intuitive way that they work in a scalar context. Because the standard behavior of putting a list into a scalar context is to *count* the list, if a slice worked with that behavior:

```
( $item = @hash{ @keys } ) == scalar @keys;
```

Which would make the expression:

```
$item = @hash{ @keys };
```

no more valuable than:

```
scalar @keys;
```

So, Perl seems to treat it like the expression:

```
$s = ( $hash{$keys[0]}, $hash{$keys[1]}, ... , $hash{$keys[$#keys]} );
```

And when a comma-delimited list is evaluated in a scalar context, it assigns the last expression. So it really ends up that

```
$item = @hash{ @keys };
```

is no more valuable than:

```
$item = $hash{ $keys[-1] };
```

But it makes writing something like this:

```
$item = $hash{ source1(), source2(), @array3, $banana, ( map { "$_" } source4()};
```

slightly easier than writing:

```
$item = $hash{ [source1(), source2(), @array3, $banana, ( map { "$_" } source4()]->[-1] }
```

But only slightly.

Comment: Actually it looks like they have a meaning - `perl -e '%h=(a=>1, b=>2); print join(" ", %h{a,b})'` prints `a 1 b 2`. I'm not sure if this is recent addition to perl though - I'm using perl 5.20 to run it.

Comment: @skmrx, that actually makes sense, Now that you mention, I've heard that something like that was in the works. I'm glad they made that change. I can throwaway my "hashsubset" library. I'll have to change the text. I wonder if `%array[0,2]` also throws out the indexes as well.

Comment: *"In Perl 5, a sigil indicates the context of your expression"* is wrong. An expression can't have a context on its own. For instance, if I write `my $last = @arr[2]` then it is in *scalar* context.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are interpolated within double quotes, so you see the actual contents of the array printed.

On the other hand, `%dict{1}` works, but is not interpolated within double quotes. So, something like `my %partial_dict = %dict{1,3}` is valid and does what you expect i.e. `%partial_dict` will now have the value `(1,2,3,4)`. But `"%dict{1,3}"` (in quotes) will still be printed as `%dict{1,3}`.

[Perl Cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch05_06.htm) has some tips on printing hashes.