# what is differnece between $arr[0] and @arr[0] in perl?

Tags: arrays, perl

I have perl coding like this

```
@arr = qw(1 2 3 4);

print $arr[0],"\n";
print @arr[0],"\n";
```

Both output answer is 1 then, What is the difference?
Is it any difference in memory storage?

Comment: `$arr[0]` is a single scalar, `@arr[0]` is a list of one scalar.

Answer (score 5):

Using the `@` sigil with an array element is using [an array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) with a single element list. If you turn on `use warnings` it will tell you:

> scalar value @arr[0] better written as $arr[0] at foo.pl line 709

If you also `use diagnostics`, it will explain quite a bit.

> Scalar value @arr[0] better written as $arr[0] at foo.pl line 709 (#1)
>
> (W syntax) You've used an array slice (indicated by @) to select a
>   single element of an array.  Generally it's better to ask for a scalar
>   value (indicated by $).  The difference is that $foo[&bar] always
>   behaves like a scalar, both when assigning to it and when evaluating
>   its argument, while @foo[&bar] behaves like a list when you assign to
>   it, and provides a list context to its subscript, which can do weird
>   things if you're expecting only one subscript.
>
> On the other hand, if you were actually hoping to treat the array
>   element as a list, you need to look into how references work, because
>   Perl will not magically convert between scalars and lists for you. 
>   See perlref.

So in general, you should use the sigil of the type of thing a variable call returns. For a single array element, that is *scalar*, so you use `$`.

Using `@` implies it returns a list. An array itself returns a list, and so does an array slice. Here you did a slice with one element. That is not a big problem, but also not the way it's intended, which is why Perl warns you about it.

Just `use warnings`, and also `use strict` (and declare your variables with `my`), and always use the correct sigil.

Don't put `use diagnostics` into your production code, as it slows everything down quite a bit. Just use it if you don't understand a warning.

Also see [this answer by brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154086/1331451).

Comment: Is it really "old-fashioned"? Was that how it worked with really old versions of Perl? In the twenty years I've been using Perl it's always just been wrong :-)

Comment: @dave I think you're right. It just didn't warn about it, I guess. I am trying to find some reference for that, as I think it might be a Perl 4 leftover, but it's really hard to find any documentation that old.

Comment: @dave I think this will make it more clear. it's not wrong per se, it's just a different thing :)